# What is the entry point for a child process in C?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, multiprocessing

Is there a way to determine the entry point of a child process?

I am trying to create 3 processes where each process has its own function and communicates with the parent process.

I have been trying to find out the entry point for a child process (in C) and am unable to reach a conclusion..

**Case 1:**

It is the starting of the main() method.
**Contradiction**: there would be infinite processes created as fork() would be called every time. Is there a way to handle this?

**Case 2:**

The entry point is right after the fork() system call().
**Contradiction**: The output of the following code:

```
int main() 
{ 
    printf("Enter ");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    { 
        if(fork() == 0) 
        { 
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    } 
}
```

"Enter" is printed 4 times in this case.

Is there is no fixed entry point then how am I supposed to write implementation for a process.

Would be great if someone could clear my confusion.

Comment: Your Case 2 is the right one: it's the point at which `fork()` returns.  The apparently contradictory behavior you're seeing is caused by buffering.  Do `fflush(stdout);` before the `fork()` and it will make more sense.